# WordPress author.php template does not work with custom permalink structure! Help!

Tags: permalinks

I just discovered a weird problem in my WP. The author archive (author.php) returns 404 error ONLY if i use custom permalink structure like /%postname%/ it shows up fine when I use the Default permalinks. What could be causing that please?

Comment: Is it only affecting the authors.php ?

Answer (score 2):

It works just fine for me. Do you have a post also named author or something? You may have some conditional statement somewhere that is dependent on the working permalink structure.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure your nickname has no spaces. To be very sure of this you could dig into yout WP database and look for `user_nicename` and remove any spaces from those values. Just a thought.